closed form for $(n+a)$th derivative of $(e^x-1)^{n}$
I worked on the summation for natural $a$
$$ \Omega_a(n)=\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k} \binom{n}{k}k^{n+a}$$
and since
$$ k^{n+a}=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{d^{n+a}}{dx^{n+a}}e^{k x}$$
So I got
$$ \Omega_a(n)=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{d^{n+a}}{dx^{n+a}} \left(e^x-1\right)^n$$
and to find nth derivative I get firstly
$$ \Omega_a(n)=\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{d^{n+a-1}}{dx^{n+a-1}} ne^x \left(e^x-1\right)^{n-1}$$
then by Leibniz rule
$$ \Omega_a(n)=n\sum_{k=0}^{n+a-1} \binom{n+a-1}{k} \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{d^k}{dx^k}\left(e^x-1\right)^{n-1}$$
and for natural $n,k$ we have
$$\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{d^k}{dx^k}\left(e^x-1\right)^{n-1}=0 , k<n-1$$
then
$$ \Omega_a(n)=n\sum_{k=n-1}^{n+a-1} \binom{n+a-1}{k} \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{d^k}{dx^k}\left(e^x-1\right)^{n-1}$$
Or
$$ \Omega_a(n)=n\sum_{k=0}^{a} \binom{n+a-1}{k+n-1} \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{d^{k+n-1}}{dx^{k+n-1}}\left(e^x-1\right)^{n-1}$$
So I found a Recurrence Relation
$$ \Omega_a(n)=n\sum_{k=0}^{a} \binom{n+a-1}{k+n-1}\Omega_k(n-1) , \Omega_n(0)=0$$
from this relation I got
$$ \Omega_0(n)=n! \\ \Omega_1(n)=\frac{n}{2} (n+1)! \\ \Omega_2(n)=\frac{n(3n+1)}{24} (n+2)! \\ \Omega_3(n)=\frac{n^2(n+1)}{48} (n+3)! \\ \Omega_4(n)=\frac{n(15n^3+30n^2+5n-2)}{5760} (n+4)! \\ \Omega_5(n)=\frac{n^2(3n^3+10n^2+5n-2)}{11520} (n+5)!$$
So we see that
$$\Omega_a(n)=P_{a}(n) (n+a)!$$
where $P_{a}(n)$ it's polynomial with $a$ degree and its coefficients are relate to A053657 and A100655
which makes sure that it's relate to Bernoulli polynomials.
So my Question is how to find the polynomial $P_{a}(n)$ ?
EDITION
from the answers I got that
$$ \Omega_a(n)=n! S_{n+a}^{(n)}$$
but I still stuck on HOW to find $P_{a}(n)$
also here there are  a similar polynomial but different signs .

Is $a$ an integer? If not, $P_a(n)$ is not a polynomial.

But if $a$ isn't an integer, and we are dealing with frqctional derivatives (the only reason you'd need to take $\lim_{x\to0}$ that I can guess) you should mention it up top.

@ThomasAndrews ok I forgot to mention that a is a natural number thanks for your comment

Fixed comment: The polynomials relate to the Stirling numbers of the second kind

Then why write it as $\lim_{x\to0}...$ rather than just $\left(\frac{d^{n+a}}{dx^{n+a}}\dots\right)_{,x=0} ?$

The function $\Omega_a(n)$ counts the number of onto functions from ${1,\dots,n+a}$ to ${1,\dots,n},$ which is $n! S(n+a,n),$ when $S(m,n)$ is the Stirling number of the second kind. No need to use derivatives

The way to see this interpretation of $\Omega$ is inclusion-exclusion.

@ThomasAndrews its just a symbol isn't it ?

What is "just a symbol?" @Faoler

@ThomasAndrews I meant using the limit

It turns out that your polynomials can be written in terms of the Norlund Polynomial with info in this article

We are interested in a closed form of
$$\Omega_a(n)
= \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k} {n\choose k} k^{n+a}$$
for natural $a.$ More  precisely we seek $P_a(n)$ where
$$P_a(n)  =  \frac{\Omega_a(n)}{(n+a)!},$$ which  is  a
polynomial. Keeping it simple we find
$$(n+a)! [z^{n+a}]
\sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k} {n\choose k} \exp(kz)
\\ = (n+a)! [z^{n+a}] (\exp(z)-1)^n
= n! {n+a\brace n}.$$
With $a$  our constant we have  combinatorially that we
are counting  the number of partitions  of $[n+a]$ into
an ordered sequence  of $n$ sets. We can  think of this
as first choosing  $n$ values to go into  our $n$ slots
for a factor of $n!  {n+a\choose n}.$ Then we partition
the $a$  remaining values into  a sequence of  $q$ sets
where $1\le q\le  a$ and attach them  at ${n\choose q}$
points to  the bottom layer of  singletons.  However we
cannot use $\exp(z)-1$ to select the sets that form the
partition of  $a$ because we  overcount by a  factor of
$m$  on $z^m$.  This  is  because if  we  select a  set
containing $m$  elements the  attachment point  has $m$
possibilities.  Hence we must  divide by $m.$ Integrate
to get  $\exp(z)-1-z$ and divide  by $z$ for an  EGF of
$(\exp(z)-1)/z-1.$ Putting it all together,
$$n! {n+a\choose n} \sum_{q=1}^a {n\choose q}
a! [z^a] ((\exp(z)-1)/z-1)^q
\\ = (n+a)! \sum_{q=1}^a {n\choose q}
[z^a] \frac{1}{z^q} (\exp(z)-1-z)^q.$$
We have our factorial in  front which is canceled. Here
we already see that we have a polynomial in $n$ because
the factors on the  binomial coefficients do not depend
on $n$ and the  binomial coefficients yield polynomials
in $n$ upon expansion. Continuing,
$$\sum_{q=1}^a {n\choose q}
[z^{a+q}] \sum_{p=0}^{q} {q\choose p}
(-1)^{q-p} z^{q-p} (\exp(z)-1)^p
\\ = \sum_{q=1}^a {n\choose q}
\sum_{p=0}^{q} {q\choose p} p!
(-1)^{q-p} [z^{a+p}] \frac{(\exp(z)-1)^p}{p!}
\\ = \sum_{q=1}^a {n\choose q}
\sum_{p=0}^{q} {q\choose p} p!
(-1)^{q-p} \frac{1}{(a+p)!} {a+p\brace p}.$$
The conclusion is that
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
P_a(n) = \frac{1}{a!} \sum_{q=1}^a {n\choose q}
\sum_{p=0}^{q} {q\choose p} (-1)^{q-p}
{a+p\choose p}^{-1}
{a+p\brace p}.}$$
We can compute an explicit  form of the coefficients of
$P_a(n)$ by using
$$[n^r] {n\choose q}
= (-1)^{q+r} \frac{1}{q!} {q\brack r}$$
which then yields
$$\bbox[5px,border:2px solid #00A000]{
P_a(n) = \frac{1}{a!} \sum_{r=1}^a n^r (-1)^r  
\sum_{q=1}^a \frac{1}{q!} {q\brack r}
\sum_{p=0}^{q} {q\choose p} (-1)^p
{a+p\choose p}^{-1}
{a+p\brace p}.}$$
The first sum in $r$ iterates over the powers of $n$ up
to $n^a$, forming a polynomial in $n$.
Remark. Once we have seen the closed form from
the combinatorial argument  it becomes readily apparent
that   we  can   also  get   it  by   simple  algebraic
manipulation, as  suggested in the comment,  which goes
as follows. We have
$$(n+a)! [z^{n+a}] (\exp(z)-1)^n
= (n+a)! [z^{n+a}] \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q}
(\exp(z)-z-1)^q z^{n-q}
\\ = (n+a)! \sum_{q=0}^n {n\choose q}
[z^{a+q}] (\exp(z)-z-1)^q.$$
Note however  that we may  set the upper range  to $a.$
This is because when  $a\gt n$ the binomial coefficient
is  zero in  the  added  range and  we  are not  adding
anything and  may raise to  $a$. On the other  hand the
sum term starts at $z^{2q}$  so we get zero when $2q\gt
q+a$ or $q\gt a.$ Hence if $a\lt n$ we may lower to $a$
because we are not losing anything. We find
$$(n+a)! \sum_{q=1}^a {n\choose q}
[z^{a+q}] (\exp(z)-z-1)^q$$
and  may   then  continue   with  the   computation  as
before.  (The  term for  $q=0$  does  not go  past  the
coefficient extractor.)

Is there an analytic/non-combinatoric way to get to $n! {n+a\choose n} \sum\limits_{q=1}^a {n\choose q}
a! [z^a] ((\exp(z)-1)/z-1)^q$?

Added algebra as suggested. Thanks!

its done thanks but is there more simple formula for $P_a(n)$ ?

You can use a “Function from exponent” from here:

$$\frac{d^nf(e^z)}{dz^n}=\sum_{k=0}^ne^{kz}s_n^{(k)}f^{(k)}(e^z)$$

which is also a pattern that can be found by making a table for $n$ and noticing the Stirling numbers of the second kind $s_n^{(k)}$. This gives:
$$\Omega_a(n)=\left.\frac{d^{n+a}}{dx^{n+a}} \left(e^x-1\right)^n\right|_0=\sum_{k=0}^{n+a}s_{n+a}^{(k)}\left.\frac{d^k(x-1)^n}{dx^k}\right|_1$$
but only the $k=n$ term survives since the other derivatives at $x=1$ give $0$:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n+a}s_{n+a}^{(k)}\left.\frac{d^k(x-1)^n}{dx^k}\right|_1=s_{n+a}^{(n)}\frac{d^n(x-1)^n}{dx^n}$$
Therefore:
$$\boxed{\Omega_a(n)= \sum_{k=0}^n (-1)^{n-k} \binom{n}{k}k^{n+a} =n!s_{n+a}^{(n)}}$$
For example, the $a=4$ case is shown here. The formula can also be found here.

You can also see this, purely combinatorially, by realizing the left side counts, by inclusion-exclusion, the number of onto functions from a set of $n+a$ elements to a set of $n$ elements. Such functions anre equivalent to partitioning the $n+a$-set and sending each part to a distinct element of the $n$-set, so you get $n!s_{n+a}^{(a)}.$

Sorry, should have been "partitioning the $n+a$-set into $n$ parts, and sending..."

nice! thank you

its nice idea but it need more work to find the polynomial I showed
